# System.AccessViolationException when calling DLL from WCF on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, dll

I've created just a test WCF service in which I need to call an external DLL.
Everything works fine under Visutal Studio development server. However, when I try to use my service on IIS I am getting this error:

> Exception:
>   System.AccessViolationException
>
> Message: Attempted to read or write
>   protected memory. This is often an
>   indication that other memory is
>   corrupt.

The stack trace leeds to the call of DLL which is presented below.
After a lot of reading and experimenting I am almost sure that the error is caused by wrong passing strings to the called function.

Here is how the wrapper for DLL looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
using System.Text;
using System;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace cdn_api_wodzu
{
        public class cdn_api_wodzu
        {

                [DllImport("cdn_api.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
             // [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.Assert, Unrestricted = true)]
                public static extern int XLLogin([In, Out] XLLoginInfo _lLoginInfo, ref int _lSesjaID);
        }
        [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public class XLLoginInfo
        {
                public int Wersja;
                public int UtworzWlasnaSesje;
                public int Winieta;
                public int TrybWsadowy;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x29)]
                public string ProgramID;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x15)]
                public string Baza;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
                public string OpeIdent;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 9)]
                public string OpeHaslo;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 200)]
                public string PlikLog;
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 0x65)]
                public string SerwerKlucza;
                public XLLoginInfo()
                {
                }
        }
}
```

this is how I call the DLL function:

```
int ErrorID = 0; int SessionID = 0;
XLLoginInfo Login;
Login = new XLLoginInfo();
Login.Wersja = 18; 
Login.UtworzWlasnaSesje = 1; 
Login.Winieta = -1; 
Login.TrybWsadowy = 1; 
Login.ProgramID = "TestProgram";
Login.Baza = "TestBase";
Login.OpeIdent = "TestUser";
Login.OpeHaslo = "TestPassword";
Login.PlikLog = "C:\\LogFile.txt";
Login.SerwerKlucza = "MyServ\\MyInstance";
ErrorID = cdn_api_wodzu.cdn_api_wodzu.XLLogin(Login, ref SessionID);
```

When I comment all the string field assigments the function works - it returns me an error message that the program ID has not been given. But when I try to assign a ProgramID  (or any other string fields, or all at once) then I am getting the mentioned exception.

I am using VS2008 SP.1, WinXP and IIS 5.1. Maybe the ISS itself is a problem?

I've tried all the workarounds that has been described here:

http://forums.asp.net/t/675515.aspx

Thansk for your time.

**After edit:** Installing Windows 2003 Server and IIS 6.0 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by specifically targeting the X86 platform when I compile. I do not know why this worked but after 2 hours of pulling my hair out I did not care.

Comment: Thanks gary. I've already tried that out and it didn't help. It was suggested on the link which I've provided.

Comment: Thank you so much, I had an `AccessViolation` in a totally different context (`System.ServiceModel`) but targeting 'AnyCPU' instead of 'x86' made it go away for me. Definitely saved me some time!

Answer (score 0):

This is an exception thrown in your un-managed code. If that code is completely black-boxed to you then you might want to reach the vendor/community regarding the issue in this particular version of the DLL you are using. It may really be a bug in the dll.

If this error happens occasionally, you might want to catch the exception and retry the call.

Comment: It happened all the time. Installing IIS 6.0 solved the problem.